# Mapping a wrapped Cauchy distribution to a uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, modeling, random-variable

I'm investigating model mismatch and have a wrapped Cauchy distribution of

```
f(x,p) = (1-p^2)/ (2*pi*(1+p^2-2p*cos(x)))
```

Is there a way to map this to a random uniform distribution, like

```
random.uniform(100, minval=-q, maxval=q)
```

i.e. If I have a value of q, what p does that equate to? Thanks

---

Edit:

I have decided to match the moments to map the parameter. The means would be 0, but the variance would give:
$\frac{1}{12} (q--q)^2 = 1- e^\gamma$

Using the substitution for $\gamma$ to get to $p$, and rearranging, I get:
$p = \sqrt{\frac{1 - \tanh (-log(1-q^2/3))}{1 + \tanh (-log(1-q^2/3))}}$
but this does not behave as expected. i.e. when $p$ is close to 1, the distribution should be tight and therefore I would expect $q \rightarrow 0$ and when $p \rightarrow 0$, $q$ should be high, but this is not what happens - does anyone spot a mistake?

Comment: Probability integral transform?

Comment: Thanks, yes looks like a probability integral transform is good to make a map between the distributions. Yes @Xi'an the $x$ is between - pi and pi

Comment: You mean you are looking for a quantile function? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2911792/cdf-and-inverse-cdf-of-wrapped-cauchy-distribution

Comment: Are you just trying to replace the wrapped Cauchy with scale parameter $p$ with a Uniform distribution with support (or scale) parameter $q$ by equating some moments? The graph of the density of a wrapped Cauchy distribution shows how much it differs from a Uniform. Besides, its support is always $(-\pi,\pi)$, for all $p$'s, which would suggest using $q=\pi$.

Answer (score 6):

Since the [wrapped Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_Cauchy_distribution#Description) is made of the superposition of truncated scaled Cauchy distributions$^1$ translated by $2n\pi$ for all $n$'s $(n\in\mathbb Z)$:
$$f_{WC}(\theta;\gamma)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{\gamma}{\pi(\gamma^2+(\theta+2\pi n)^2)}\,\mathbb I_{(-\pi,\pi)}(\theta)\qquad \gamma>0$$
it can be simulated by

1. Simulating a regular Cauchy variate $X$ with scale$^2$ $\gamma$
2. Translating the realisation $x$ of $X$ by the proper amount $2n\pi$ so that it belongs to $(-\pi,\pi)$ and returning the resulting $\theta=X+2n\pi$

Furthermore, the Cauchy distribution enjoys closed-form pdf and closed-form inverse pdf, which means that $X$ can be generated by the inverse pdf transform as
$$X = \gamma\tan(\pi U-\pi/2)\qquad U\sim\mathcal U(0,1)$$
Therefore the random variable $\theta\sim f_{WC}(\theta;\gamma)$ can be written (and simulated) as
$$\theta = [\gamma\tan(\pi U-\pi/2)+\pi]\ \text{mod}\,(2\pi) - \pi\tag{1}\qquad U\sim\mathcal U(0,1)$$

As an R code, this translates into

```
rwauchy <- function(n=1,gamma=1) (tan(pi*(runif(n)-.5))*gamma+pi)%%(2*pi)-pi
```

and the fit of the histogram with the density $f_{WC}$ is illustrated below

[image]

---

$^1$Formula cut&pasted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_Cauchy_distribution#Description).

$^2$The correspondence between $\gamma$ and $p$ is$$\gamma=\tanh^{-1}\frac{1-p^2}{1+p^2}$$

Comment: Thanks @Xi'an I forgot to mention my wrapping for the Cauchy distribution, but I also get this. Now I'd like to have a map between a uniform distribution and the wrapped Cauchy....if this is even possible, perhaps a rough map would work for low values?

Comment: thanks, so I start with my uniform distribution $U(q)$ and generate a random number between $-q$ and $q$. I put this into eqn (1), and I'd like to find $p$. We know how $p$ and $\gamma$ relate. Eqn(1) gives me $\theta$ given some $\gamma$ and my random number. I'm not sure we know enough?

Comment: Because all I know is the $q$ I used to generate the random number from $U[-q,q]$ and now I'd like an equivalent $p$, if possible?

Comment: Could I pick a $\theta$ to assess the equation at, say, in the tail of the distribution?

Comment: So I decided to test the distributions at 25%. For the uniform distribution, that occurs at $x=0.25*(q--q) + -q = -0.5q$. I wrote code to find the 25% in the wrapped cauchy: ```prange = np.linspace(0.05,0.95,1000)
twentyfive = np.zeros(len(prange))

for pp in range(len(prange)):

  wc_int = np.arctan2(prange[pp]-1,(prange[pp]+1)*np.tan(x/2))/np.pi
  plt.plot(x,wc_int+1)
  twentyfive[pp] = wc_int.flat[np.abs(wc_int +1 - 0.25).argmin()]


plt.show()  

plt.plot(prange,twentyfive)
plt.show()
plt.plot(twentyfive/-0.5) ``` but I'm not sure it matches well